# Exporting Reports to Excel in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Whenever I try to export my report to a Excel the single column in my reports tend to be in two columns in the Excel sheet after exporting .

I want them in a single column. Is there any solution for my problem

THanks !!

Comment: Export to csv file format instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! the solution is simple. if you look at your report in design view, the place that becomes 2 columns (splits) has some other TextBox or table border above or below it. The key is to look at borders vertically. Anything that is considered a border, splits into two cells. There is no other way for SSRS to create it in Excel. when you align all these border lines (Visual Studio and Report Builder offer helper lines when you move a border) there will be no more split cells in Excel.

Also, consider the size of each cell. The best practice is to keep these sizes normal (not like 3.264891 in) You can overwrite these sizes in the property pane.